# ios wkwebview html text should scale on different devices and keep same number of lines and same line breaks

Tags: android, html, ios, css, xamarin

I'm developing under xamarin iOS and android. I want to show on iOS a webview with html content formatted in a specific font and size in pixel so that it keeps number of lines and line breaks on every device and test should be scaled. My problem is that the html text has different number of lines on different devices(even if html uses px as font size).

On iOS I'm using a WkWebview with no webviewconfiguration

```
LoadHtmlString(htmlString, bundleUrl);
```

[image: iphone 7 landscape]

[image: ipad pro landscape]

On android I'm using a Webview with

```
Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

LoadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

On android it is working fine on different devices.

[image]

I tried a lot with html viewport settings, and wkwebview webconfigurations but I can't get this behaviour working also on iOS with WKWebview.

HTML text:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=399,height=288, user-scalable=no'>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: Lato;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: url(\"Fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf\");
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: Lato;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: url(\"Fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf\");
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: Lato;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 700;
            src: url(\"Fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf\");
        }

        @font-face {
            font-family: Lato;
            font-style: italic;
            font-weight: 700;
            src: url(\"Fonts/Lato-BoldItalic.ttf\");
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: transparent;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        ol {
            list-style-type: decimal;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: disc;
        }

        ol,
        ul {
            display: block;
            -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
            -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
            -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
            -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
            -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <span style=\ "font-family: Lato, sans-serif\">
            <em>Compliance with corporate security measures protects internal company information from unauthorized access, helping
                safeguard your company from damages. </em>
        </span>
        <span style=\ "font-family: &quot;PT Sans&quot;, sans-serif; font-size: 16px\">\n</span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span style=\ "font-family: Lato, sans-serif\">
            <em>The aim of this training is to strengthen your knowledge and awareness of the secure handling of information.
                Together we can achieve a high level of security awareness protecting the value of our company.</em>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anybody have an idea what settings I'm missing?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `px` will render to different size depending on your screen's resolution, you can try `vm`. Did you deploy it on Android device with same resolution? I think this may be the problem of your html file.

Comment: Because I have the same view also in the web-app(browser) and it should look the same on mobile devices no matter which resolution. So the text should scale respectively that number of lines and line-breaks are the same.

Comment: Maybe it has also something todo with the android webview settings usewideviewport and loadwithoverviewmode but I‘m not sure how I can set this on iOS WKWebview...

Comment: Changing px to vm does not change anything. The font size still looks the sam eon different devices and does not scale...

Comment: What I do not get is why on iOS WKWebview the font-size 12px does not look differently on different screen resolutions.

Comment: I found a solution:
If I scale all px values with the device screen factor(calculate from devicewidth to default white area width from screenshots also used to position the yellow html view) it is looking good and the html text scales on the different devices on iOS. Strange is just that this is not needed on androids webview...